# Div grow's with sticky element

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I need a sticky element that stops before the footer. Is it somehow possible with a sticky element to make sure the red background does not grow with the sticky div? Right now if I increase the height of the sticky element the red div grows. (The sticky element cannot have a scrollable body, in this case).

Demo:

```html
<div class="bg-red-500 h-[1200px]">
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="bg-blue-500">
      <p>Div 1</p>
    </div>

      <div class="bg-yellow-500 sticky top-[100px] h-[200px] ml-auto right-[100px] max-w-[100px]">
       <p>Div 2 (sticky)</p>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="h-[900px] bg-green-500">Div 3 (content)</div>
  </div>
  
  <footer class="h-[400px] bg-black">
     <p class="text-white">footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native css solution to this, but there are plenty of workarounds.

One would be to script the bottom margin to be the negative value of the sticky elements size

```html
<div class="bg-red-500 h-[1200px]">
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="bg-blue-500">
      <p>Div 1</p>
    </div>

      <div class="bg-yellow-500 sticky top-[100px] h-[200px] ml-auto right-[100px] max-w-[100px]">
       <p>Div 2 (sticky)</p>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="h-[900px] bg-green-500">Div 3 (content)</div>
  </div>
  
  <footer class="h-[400px]  bg-black">
     <p class="text-white">footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
  let stickyElement = document.getElementsByClassName("bg-yellow-500")[0];
  let height = stickyElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  let marginTop = Number(stickyElement.style.marginTop.slice(0,-2));
  stickyElement.style.marginBottom = "-"+(height+marginTop)+"px";
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I had 2 red divs, I mean the red div at the top. (made the footer black now).

Comment: @Jamie well I now edited the footer black, too. But I didn't need to change anything else

Comment: The green content still grow'w with the sticky element

Comment: @Jamie The green content is exactly 900px, just as you defined in its class `class="h-[900px] bg-green-500"`